# Performance difference in handling data

Tags: python, flask

I have a MySQL table with a column called `countrycode` and it contains phone codes of different countries. On my website I need to display the country names near the country code, however there is no matching data in the database.

So I have two options, adding a new column for the countries and update it with the country names. Or I can write a function that returns the proper country names at page loads. The function would be something like this:

```
def return_country(countrycode):
     if "1" == countrycode:
         return "USA"
     #and so on...
```

My question is that is there any serious time/performance difference between the two solution? I assume getting the values from the database would be better, however if there is no radical difference I may use the function.

Comment: `#and so on...` should be replaced by a dictionary. No if statements. For example. `{"1": "USA"}[countrycode]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flask is rendering a template from the data, I assume? Adding one more web-server function call for a simple lookup wouldn't be the worst, but it could add up depending on the amount of data you have.

Your code could rather be written as

```
# Or load this from a JSON file
COUNTRIES = {
    "1": "USA"
}

def return_country(countrycode):
     if countrycode not in COUNTRIES:
         return None
     else:
         return COUNTRIES[countrycode]
```

The more performant solution is to add the column in the database, though.